# html5mode in angular not working

Tags: angularjs, apache

Trying to use html5mode following [this](https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/03/09/angularjs-html5-mode-or-pretty-urls-on-apache-using-htaccess/) tutorial.Things that I have done -

1. in config closure of `app.js`

   `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`
2. inside head tag of index.html. Deploying app in `test.com` so

   `<base href="/">`
3. rewrite configuration in apache vhost conf.

   `<Directory D:/wamp/www/test.com>
      RewriteEngine On

     # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
     RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
     RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
     RewriteRule ^ - [L]
     # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
     RewriteRule ^ /index.html
   </Directory>`

Having done these steps, I restarted apache.
Results : When I visited suburl-

1. `test.com/dashboard` it was redirecting to `test.com`.
2. `test.com/#/dashboard` url is deformed to `test.com/#%2Fdashboard`. when I hit refresh it redirected back to `test.com`.

Routing -

```
.config(['$routeProvider','$httpProvider','$locationProvider', 
    function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $tu="templates/";
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", { templateUrl:$tu+'home/index.html' })
    .when("/dashboard", {templateUrl:$tu+'dashboard/index.html'})
    .when("/notes", {templateUrl:$tu+'notes/index.html'})
     $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
     $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }])
```

I have gone through docs also and other tutorials, but failed to make it work/understand completely. Help please!!

Comment: Its a little tough to figure out how to fix this with the little bit of code that you have provided.  How exactly is the routing set up?

Comment: @JonBlack added routes's details

Comment: Could you show the entire configuration setup?  These bits and pieces still aren't giving me the whole picture.